# How can I pass variable action of form in flask using if-else and jinja2 templates?

Tags: python, if-statement, flask, jinja2

In the action stated in the form below, I wish to pass either summary_url or summary_text, since either of one is empty. Therefore I use the following code before stating action :

```
                        {% if summary_url == "" %}
                        {% set summary_url = summary_text %}
                        {% endif %}

                         <form action= "{{ url_for("save_summary",
         summary=summary_url, param="string with spaces") }}" method="post">
```

But the value of summary_text is not getting updated ,even after applying this code.?
Is there a way to use if-else in action of form ??

Comment: I tried using namespace but even  that did not work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest quotation marks like that.  The browser cannot parse.  Try:

```
diagnosing before: <br /><br />

summary_text before: {{ summary_text }}<br />
summary_url before: {{ summary_url }}<br /><br />

{% set summary_url = summary_text if summary_url == "" %}

diagnosing after: <br /><br />

summary_text after: {{ summary_text }}<br />
summary_url after: {{ summary_url }}<br /><br />

<form action= '{{ url_for("save_summary", summary=summary_url, param="string with spaces") }}' method="post">
```

Also, note that you are not sending `summary_url` to the backend.  The variable name you are sending is `summary`.

Comment: @app.route('/save_summary/<string:summary>',methods=["POST","GET"])
def save_summary(summary): , yes , I am sending summary to the backend, but again my summary_text remains empty after using the above mentioned code @GAEfan.